# Human readable delta time text to Python `timedelta`

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, parsing

I have seen many examples on how to parse a human readable text containing a  date/time to `datetime` structure or even seconds since "Epoch".

A few Pyhton libraries (e.g. `parsedatetime` or `dateparser` claim to be able to parse relative date/times (like "1min 47 seconds ago") but the end result is always anchored to a specific date/time.

Example using two mentioned libraries:

```
sdate="1 min 37 seconds ago"
dateparser.parse(sdate)
datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 19, 17, 20, 29, 325230)
pdtCal.parse(sdate)
(time.struct_time(tm_year=2019, tm_mon=8, tm_mday=19, tm_hour=17, tm_min=22, tm_sec=49, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=231, tm_isdst=-1), 2)
```

What I need, though, is something as simple as a `timedelta` object, but from what I could learn, the best I can do is to compute the `timedelta` by subtracting the parsed `datetime` from current time.

Obviously, this is not the same since I will be adding a sampling error (`datetime.datetime.now()` is running at a different time as the parser run).

So I ask, is there a simple yet relieble way in Python to parse this delta time text directly into a `timedelta` object or a scalar value (e.g seconds count)?

Thanks!

Comment: "`datetime.datetime.now()` is running at a different time as the parser run" Assuming it will be in the same function, that "different time" is going to be what, several nano/milli seconds at most?

Comment: So the problem is that you want maximum accuracy of the following action: 

timedelta = this_moment - parsed_date ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to specify "anchor date" in `dateparser` using [settings](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#settings):

```
In [1]: from dateparser import parse
In [2]: from datetime import datetime

In [3]: anchor_date = datetime(2020, 1, 1)
In [4]: parsed_date = parse('1 min 37 seconds ago', settings={'RELATIVE_BASE': anchor_date})
In [5]: parsed_date - anchor_date
Out[5]: datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=86303)
```

Using the same date as relative base and in delta calculation ensures precise results.